# A question about Producer-Consumer Model in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I write a Java program to solve Producer Consumer problem in Multi-Threads. But it can not work correctly.
The program:

```
public class ConsumerAndProducer {
static int  products = 0;
static int capacity = 10;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Producer()).start();
    new Thread(new Consumer()).start();
}
static class Consumer implements Runnable{

    public void consume() {
        synchronized (ConsumerAndProducer.class){
            if(products <= 0){
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            products--;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Consumer, remain：" + products);
            if(products == 9){
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            consume();
        }
    }
}
static class Producer implements Runnable{

    public void produce() {
        synchronized (ConsumerAndProducer.class){
            if(products == capacity){
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            products++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Producer, remain：" + products);
            if(products == 1){
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            produce();
        }
    }
}
```

And the errors:

```
Producer, remain：1
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at zhousai.ConsumerAndProducer$Producer.produce(ConsumerAndProducer.java:69)
    at zhousai.ConsumerAndProducer$Producer.run(ConsumerAndProducer.java:77)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Consumer, remain：0
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at zhousai.ConsumerAndProducer$Consumer.consume(ConsumerAndProducer.java:22)
    at zhousai.ConsumerAndProducer$Consumer.run(ConsumerAndProducer.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: never call Thread.sleep() inside synchronized statement or method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your code, I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner
```

The line of your code throwing that exception is the call to method `wait()`.
You are calling method `wait()` of class `Producer` but you are synchronizing on `ConsumerAndProducer.class`. The `wait()` method must be called on the object that you are synchronizing on, because that object owns the lock and you must call `wait()` on the object that owns the lock. Hence the error message: `current thread not owner`.

The simplest solution is to change your code such that you call `ConsumerAndProducer.class.wait()` rather than just `wait()`.

Here is your code with my suggested fix:

```java
public class ConsumerAndProducer {
    static int  products = 0;
    static int capacity = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Producer()).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer()).start();
    }

    static class Consumer implements Runnable {
        public void consume() {
            synchronized (ConsumerAndProducer.class){
                if (products <= 0) {
                    try {
                        ConsumerAndProducer.class.wait(); // change here
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                products--;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Consumer, remain：" + products);
                if(products == 9){
                    ConsumerAndProducer.class.notify(); // change here
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                consume();
            }
        }
    }

    static class Producer implements Runnable{
        public void produce() {
            synchronized (ConsumerAndProducer.class){
                if (products == capacity) {
                    try {
                        ConsumerAndProducer.class.wait(); // change here
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                products++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Producer, remain：" + products);
                if(products == 1){
                    ConsumerAndProducer.class.notify(); // change here
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                produce();
            }
        }
    }
}
```